# If I delete all users in my table, the option to add users disappears as well. #STUMPED

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

**PHP - AJAX, and MySqli**

I have a small application that allows me to add or delete a first and last name to a database within the webpage. I am using AJAX so the page updates instantly w/out refreshing. My issue is that if I delete all the users from the page, the ability to add user also disappears. Consequently, this is triggering my "if, else" statement to fire and I am left with a user table that reads simply, "Data not found". Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");  
 $output = '';  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id ASC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 $output .= '  
      <div id="table">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  

                     <th width="40%">First Name</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Last Name</th>  
                     <th width="20%">Delete</th>  
                </tr>';  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  

                     <td class="first_name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["first_name"].'</td>  
                     <td class="last_name" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["last_name"].'</td>  
                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '  
           <tr>  
                <td></td>  
                <td id="first_name" contenteditable></td>  
                <td id="last_name" contenteditable></td>  
                <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
           </tr>  
      ';  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>  
                     </tr>';  
 }  
 $output .= '</table>  
      </div>'; 
 echo $output;  
 ?>
```

Comment: remove the html part where you add users `      $output .= '  
           <tr>  
                <td></td>  
                <td id="first_name" contenteditable></td>  
                <td id="last_name" contenteditable></td>  
                <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
           </tr>  
      ';  ` outside the `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) ` check, looks like it should be where you have ` $output .= '</table>  `

Comment: just put your add user code outside of if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I delete all users in my table, the option to add users disappears as well.

Sure, because the row with add user button...

```
  $output .= '  
       <tr>  
            <td></td>  
            <td id="first_name" contenteditable></td>  
            <td id="last_name" contenteditable></td>  
            <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
       </tr>  
  ';
```

Is inside this

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
{   
    // [...]
}
```

If you get no rows (users) the html table row with the button is not appended to output.

---

Move the whole block at the end, just before

```
$output .= '</table>  
</div>';
```

outside of the `if` block

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been staring at this forever trying to figure out where I went wrong.